# how to call a method immediately after thread run() ends?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to call a method that returns a string value. Actually this string value is an instance variable, and `run()` method put the value of the string.

So, I want to call a method to get the string value updated by thread `run()` method..

How can I do it...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Whatever implements Runnable {
    private volatile String string;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        string = "whatever";
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Whatever whatever = new Whatever();
        Thread thread = new Thread(whatever);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        String string = whatever.getString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Check out [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) which is a Runnable that can return a result.

You use it like this:

You write a Callable instead of a Runnable, for example:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
  public Integer call () {
    // do something that takes really long...
    return 1;
  }
}
```

You kick it of by submitting it to an ExecutionService:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor ();
Future<Integer> task = es.submit(new MyCallable());
```

You get back the [FutureTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) handle which will hold the result once the task is finished:

```
Integer result = task.get ();
```

FutureTask provides more methods, like `cancel`, `isDone` and `isCancelled` to cancel the execution and ask for the status. The get method itself is blocking and waits for the task to finish. check out the javadoc for details.

Comment: Why create a new FutureTask instead of just submitting the Callable directly?  I think that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Callable<String>` instead, submit it to an `ExecutorService`, and then call `get()` on the `Future<String>` it returns when you submit it.

Comment: Ahh yeah, Tim took my answer and gave you a good example so I'll leave it at that.